# Display Github repository files directly in a blog

Tags: git, github, syntax-highlighting

I have a blog and I'd like to add some code snippets in some of my posts.

I found this "gist" thing pretty handy but looks like it only works with code you directly paste in. I'm already familiar with syntax highlighter and similar tools but still doesn't cover my requirement.

I'd find really useful a tool which allow you to display Github repository files directly within your blog. Imagine giving gist the url of your repository file and you pasting the source gist provides into your post.

Is there a way to link files in a public Github repository so I can display them in my blog as a code snippet?

Comment: Yup very very easily done, example : https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed

Comment: But in all these examples I need to paste my classes from my repository into gist... What I want is something like this:
   <code data-gist-id="https://github.com/user/repo/blob/master/m/test.cs"></code>
where I just provide to gist the file I want to wrap up.

Comment: Got a solution for your @Rober - take a look below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually do this using a tool called [Gist-it](http://gist-it.appspot.com/).

> Usage
>
> Take a github file url and prefix it with http://gist-it.appspot.com and embed the result within a  tag:
>
> ```
> <script src="http://gist-it.appspot.com/http://github.com/$file"></script>
> ```
>
> $file should follow the github repository pattern of 
>   $user/$repository/raw/master/$path
>   github/$file is a shorthand for http://github.com/$file and works in the same way

Here's a test I just made by following their guidelines.

[image]

Works!

Comment: Thanks mate! that  looks great

Comment: Thanks. works very well. See here a trick to intellipaste such links: https://tdalon.blogspot.com/blogger-embed-github-file

Comment: must be noted that you must trust this site since their javascript is going to run in the context of your site